# Redirection in Django command called from another command results in extraneous newlines. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

#### The Setup

For the purpose of illustrating the problem, I have created these commands in my project:

`foo.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("foo")
        # I pass `self.stdout` here explicitly because if `foo` is
        # redirected, I want `baz` redirected too.
        call_command('baz', stdout=self.stdout)
```

`baz.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # This could be reduced to one call to self.stdout.write
        # but this code is meant to minimally reproduce what happens in a 
        # complex command where multiple self.stdout.write calls are
        # made. If the code here were replaced with a single call, it 
        # would cease to reproduce the issue.
        self.stdout.write("baz ", ending='')

        # Imagine a lot of stuff happening here with conditionals and
        # loops.
        self.stdout.write("baz")
```

#### Actual Behavior

I run `foo` like this:

```
./manage.py foo
```

And I get this output to the console:

```
foo
baz 
baz
```

#### Desired Behavior

What I want is the output to the console to be:

```
foo
baz baz
```

Note that when I invoke `baz` directly with `./manage.py baz`, I get this output:

```
baz baz
```

There is no newline between the two "baz". I want the same layout when `baz` is invoked through `foo`.

Comment: Linking back: [Spurious newlines added in Django management commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37400807/674039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

The reason it is not working is that Django uses an [`OutputWrapper`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c296e55dc6a697c7e4d4be92b954633cda4a79b1/django/core/management/base.py#L82) object to wrap whatever is passed as the `stdout` argument of a `Command`. This object becomes `self.stdout` in the command's methods. (This is true in Django 1.8 and as far as I can tell as far back as Django 1.5.)

`OutputWrapper` has a `write` method which by default adds a newline to what is written to the output. You can turn it off with `ending=''`, which is what you do and works fine when `baz` is invoked directly. However, the `OutputWrapper` object does not expect that it will be wrapping another `OutputWrapper` object. When your `baz` code is called through `foo` and executes `self.stdout.write("baz ", ending='')` it calls `write` on the object it is wrapping, but it does not forward the `ending=''` parameter. So the `OutputWrapper` that was created for `foo` is called without `ending=''` and a newline is output to the console.

#### Solutions

The solution I prefer is to replicate in my code exactly what Django does when it decides what `OutputWrapper` should wrap:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("foo\n")
        call_command('baz', stdout=options.get('stdout', sys.stdout))
```

The `stdout=options.get('stdout', sys.stdout)` bit will pass `sys.stdout` if no `stdout` keyword parameter was given to `foo`. Otherwise, it forwards the `stdout` keyword parameter. You can do the same with `stderr` by changing all instances of `stdout` to `stderr`.

Another way would be to set the ending of the `OutputWrapper` to `''`, like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.ending = ''
        self.stdout.write("foo\n")
        call_command('baz')
```

You then have to write your command while keeping in mind that you always have to output newlines explicitly: this is why we now have `self.stdout.write("foo\n")`, with a newline at the end of the string. This has the advantage that anything that `baz` outputs appears immediately on the console, so if it hangs after some output, you at least have something to work with. However, `OutputWrapper` is not a class that has been documented for direct use by Django projects. This solution basically uses an API that could change without warning in newer releases of Django.