# Spurious newlines added in Django management commands

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, stdout, django-management-command

Running Django v1.10 on Python 3.5.0:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('hello ', end='', file=self.stdout)
        print('world', file=self.stdout)
```

Expected output:

```
hello world
```

Actual output:

```
hello 

world
```

How do I correctly pass the ending character?  I currently use a workaround of setting explicitly:

```
 self.stdout.ending = ''
```

But this hack means you don't get all the features of the print function, you must use `self.stdout.write` and prepare the bytes manually.

Comment: Is your use-case more long the lines of building up a whole text string based on coniditionals etc.  The reason I ask is, if the whole string is known in advance, such as in the case of "hello world" you could have easily written out as a the full line while using print without stdout.write to avail the control over the newline ending character.  So assuming that you do not know the text ahead of time, can you not build the text by string appends until the full text is ready for printing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926422/redirection-in-django-command-called-from-another-command-results-in-extraneous . And if you don't find a solution, I recommend writing a decorator or context manager temporarily patching `print` and/or `self.stdout` to behave the way you want.

Comment: I don't get how using `self.stdout.ending = ''` "prevents [you] from using the print function and all its nice features". You can still use `print`, and the output will be what you expect so what's the problem?

Comment: @Louis No, did you actually try it?  It still adds extra newlines and seems to ignores the `end` kwarg.

Comment: This issue prevents me from using a console-based progress bar for long-running management commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When setting `self.stdout.ending` explicitly, the print command works as expected.

The line ending needs to be set in `self.stdout.ending` when `file=self.stdout`, because that is an instance of `django.core.management.base.OutputWrapper`.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.ending = ''
        print('hello ', end='', file=self.stdout)
        print('world', file=self.stdout)
```

Returns

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 14):

As is mentioned in [Django 1.10's Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) document:

> When you are using management commands and wish to provide console output, you should write to **self.stdout** and **self.stderr**, instead of printing to **stdout** and **stderr** directly. By using these proxies, it becomes much easier to test your custom command. *Note also that you don’t need to end messages with a newline character, it will be added automatically, unless you specify the ending parameter*:
>
> ```
> self.stdout.write("Unterminated line", ending='')
> ```

Hence, in order to print in your `Command` class, you should define your `handle()` function as:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("hello ", ending='')
        self.stdout.write("world", ending='')

# prints: hello world
```

Also, by explicitly setting `self.stdout.ending = ''`, you are modifying the property of `self.stdout` object. But you may not want this to be reflected in future calls of `self.stdout.write()`. Hence it will be better to use `ending` parameter within `self.stdout.write()` function (as demonstrated in sample code above).

As you mentioned *"But this hack means you don't get all the features of the print function, you must use self.stdout.write and prepare the bytes manually."* No, you do not have to worry about creating the `bytes` or other features of `print()`, as [`self.stdout.write()`](http://fossies.org/dox/Django-1.10.2/classdjango_1_1core_1_1management_1_1base_1_1OutputWrapper.html#a100ad4bd24e087ee23ff3376ba7e9be0) function belonging to [`OutputWrapper`](http://fossies.org/dox/Django-1.10.2/classdjango_1_1core_1_1management_1_1base_1_1OutputWrapper.html) class expects data to be in `str` format. Also I would like to mention that `print()` and `OutputWrapper.write()` behaves quite similar both acting as a wrapper around [`sys.stdout.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).

The only difference between `print()` and `OutputWrapper.write()` is:

- `print()` accepts message string as `*args` with `separator` parameter to join the the multiple strings, whereas
- `OutputWrapper.write()` accepts single message string

But this difference could be easily handled by explicitly joining the strings with *separator* and passing it to `OutputWrapper.write()`.

**Conclusion:** You do not have to worry about the additional features provided by `print()` as there are none, and should go ahead with using `self.stdout.write()` as suggested in this answer's quoted content from [Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) document.

If you are interested, you may check the source code of `BaseCommand` and `OutputWrapper` classes available at: [Source code for `django.core.management.base`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/management/base/). It might help in clearing some of your doubts. You may also check [PEP-3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#specification) related to Python 3's `print()`.

Comment: Thanks, your claims check out!  This design of `OutputWrapper` was a poor decision, it causes `self.stdout` to violate the principle of least surprise.  You expect it to behave like `sys.stdout`, but it doesn't, meaning you can't use `self.stdout` together with the print function properly unless you RTFM.  This has caught me up in testing a few times, now I finally understand the reasons!  Imho the interface should have matched `sys.stdout`.  Either that, or we should have a wrapper named `self.print` instead.

Comment: I already had an idea that you are considering `self.stdout` as `sys.stdout`, that's why I mentioned *"self.stdout.write() function belonging to OutputWrapper class expects data to be in str format. Also I would like to mention that print() and OutputWrapper.write() behaves quite similar both acting as a wrapper around sys.stdout.write()."*

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `self.stdout` is an instance of `django.core.management.base.OutputWrapper` command. Its `write` expects an `str`, not `bytes`, thus you can use

```
self.stdout.write('hello ', ending='')
self.stdout.write('world')
```

Actually `self.stdout.write` does accept bytes but only whenever the `ending` **is** an empty string - that's because its `write` method is defined

```
def write(self, msg, style_func=None, ending=None):
    ending = self.ending if ending is None else ending
    if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):
        msg += ending
    style_func = style_func or self.style_func
    self._out.write(force_str(style_func(msg)))
```

If `ending` is true, then `msg.endswith(ending)` will fail if `msg` is a `bytes` instance and ending is a `str`.

Furthermore, `print` with `self.stdout` does work correctly when I set the `self.stdout.ending = ''` explicitly; however doing this might mean that other code that uses `self.stdout.write` expecting it to insert newlines, would fail.

---

In your case, what I'd do is to define a `print` method for the `Command`:

```
from django.core.management.base import OutputWrapper

class PrintHelper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def write(self, s):
        if isinstance(self.wrapped, OutputWrapper):
            self.wrapped.write(s, ending='')
        else:
            self.wrapped.write(s)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def print(self, *args, file=None, **kwargs):
        if file is None:
            file = self.stdout
        print(*args, file=PrintHelper(file), **kwargs)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.print('hello ', end='')
        self.print('world')
```

You can make this into your own `BaseCommand` subclass - and you can use it with different files too:

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for c in '|/-\\' * 100:
            self.print('\rhello world: ' + c, end='', file=self.stderr)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self.print('\bOK')
```